# Is there a noticeable downside in turning on file integrity of ReFS?

Tags: refs

Since the advantages of ReFS was that the system keeps checking file corruption,

> The key design advantages of ReFS include automatic integrity checking and data scrubbing,  -- Wikipedia, ReFS

I had been thinking the system should be doing that automatically. Then I discovered that file integrity is set to disabled by default. There seems to be ways to enable it, but since Microsoft has disabled it by default, does this mean that Microsoft recommends not using it? It seems that it is only enabled for metadata, and I am not exactly sure what metadata is, but I guess most consumers would rather be interested in keeping their actual data intact than the metadata.

In short, is there a noticeable downside in turning on file integrity of ReFS that Microsoft had to disable it by default?